# Foundation framework memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, core-foundation

We have created an iPhone application which has lot of images in that and we are using facebooker plugin. When we are checking for the memory leaks, it shows lots of memory leaks in foundation framework and CoreGrapics. If anyone will be having any idea about this, please share it with me.

Thanks

Comment: Core Foundation and Core Graphics are not leaking, the uses of them in your application are.  You're seeing these leaks in Instruments, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

What specifically is leaking? Note that UIImage will cache images so that UIImage doesn't have to keep reloading them if it's called again.

Answer (score 0):

Core Foundation is not leaking. What leaks is trying to tell you is that an object in Core Foundation leaked because you have not released it, before pointing your variable to other object.

Could you please post some code of the leak so we can help you out?.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet you are returning `cell` without autoreleasing it, from a method that should return an autoreleased object, so that's at least part of the leak you are seeing.